# Modified Preorder Tree Traversal - Display Only 2 of each child

Tags: php, mysql, tree-traversal

i'm trying to figure out how to use the MPTTD using [sitepoint's](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) tutorial.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT title, lft, rgt FROM tree '.  
'WHERE lft BETWEEN '.$row['lft'].' AND '.  
$row['rgt'].' ORDER BY lft ASC;');
```

the root has lft = 1, rgt = 42
so if i used lft = 1, rgt = 42 .. it would return

A A1 A2 A3 A4 B B1 B2 B3 B4 C C1 C2 C3 C4 D D1 D2 D3 D4

how do i retrieve only the 1st and 2nd child from the descendants like this

A A1 A2 B B1 B2 C C1 C2 D D1 D2

thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Option 1: First get the left and right value. Then use left and right value. Select * from table where left=2 and right=17. Option 2: To get each descendants you can use the left value and any number of children for example where left=2 between left+2. For example:

```
   $result = mysql_query('SELECT title, lft, rgt FROM tree '.  
   'WHERE lft BETWEEN '.$row['lft'].' AND '. $row['lft']+2.' ORDER BY lft ASC;');
```

Comment: thank you for replying..
yes, using the left and right value will give me the descendants. but i only need the first 2 child of each descendant.

Comment: You can modify your query and search between left=2 and left+2?